# Configure WOL with OpenVPN

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn

My server is a PC with Linux Ubuntu. This server is always on but most of the time in standby mode. This server is an OpenVPN server too.

I have many client (Android smartphone, or Windows laptop) that I can connect  with OpenVPN, and it works when is everything switched on or when I am connected in the same network of the server. 
For example if the address of my laptop is 192.168.1.6 and the address of the server is 192.168.1.10 I can connect them with OpenVPN.

I am out of my office and out of my network. I want with my laptop wake the suspended server and connect with openVPN. What I have to do?

If it is not clear, ask me what can I describe better.

Comment: You want to VPN into your home network in order to WOL the VPN server? I'm afraid that's not going to work.

Comment: From my laptop (in my home network) I want WOL the server (in the work-place network) that is suspended. Then, connect them with OpenVPN.

Comment: Are you in charge of the company network?

Comment: Yes i am the administrator

Comment: Okay, fine. What exactly prevents you from keeping the vpn server running? Can you connect from outside the company network while the server is running?

Comment: I have the server in the office only to store some data and for versioning. I would access to the server from outside rarely, so i would like to know if i can keep the server suspended and resume it only when needed (noise for other people, power consumption). But it seems it's not possible. Maybe the best solution is keep the server on anyway

Comment: It probably is. You could also always look into any VPN options your firewall/gateway gives you, which I assume will keep running whatsoever.

Comment: Is this actually an Enterprise server? Or is it just a tower you threw Linux on? If it's actually a server platform, i.e poweredge or similar. You can use the management network interface to turn-on / restart.